# Sending requests - provide a dictionary or a string

Tags: python, plsql, request

I was to automate action using python requests, when encountered strange behavior.

I want to generate reports from a certain domain, to do so I have to send a POST request providing parameters in form of an XML. In devtools it looks like this:

> xmlWe: <REPORTPARS><PROC_ID>11</PROC_ID>
> .....     and so on

when I send report data by python requests, it works perfectly whe provided a with dictionary:

> data = dict(xmlWe = '<REPORTPARS><PROC_ID>11</PROC_ID>(...) '
>
> r = s.post(URL_generate, data=data))

IMO, its kind of strange, dictionary is a type in python so why would this server handle or expect this type?

I was trying to send this XML as text or JSON, adding the corresponding header 'Content-type' but without success. The server will return 777 Java nullptr exception, which is the same as in case of sending any other nonsense datatype. So it looks like he was expecting some sort of dictionary.

My problem is, my company uses *pl/sql* for automation, so I will finally have to use this language. There, in *http_utils* data can be sent merely by *write_text*, so I'm restricted to sending string (can be dumped JSON).

What do You think, Is there an option for this server will accept report_pars as a string by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a xml directly:

```
import requests

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
r = requests.post(URL_generate, data=xmlWe, headers=headers)
```

Comment: You mean, to send just the xml as string: data='<REPORTPARS>(...) >' ?
When i do, i get the same error, 777. It seems like the string datatype was not allowed. I sent content-type header too.

Comment: I tried adding prolog:

> xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><REPORTPARS>(...) >'
and converting to bytes:
> ... data=xml.encode()
but still didn't help